Terminal opened in Ubuntu but command prompt does not appear
When I open my terminal in Ubuntu, it opens, but I have no command prompt! I can't write any commands. I tried to reset it, but nothing happened.
The image below shows how the terminal opens and how it gets stuck at the beginning:

The terminal stays like that, so what should I do?

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [edit] your question and add the content of your ~/.bashrc file.

Check the files ~/.bashrc and ~/.profilerc and remove anything you've added.
Those two files execute when you start a new shell. This problem can happen if you put something very slow into one of those files.
It could also be a slow command in your prompt. Try adding this at the bottom of ~/.bashrc:
export PS1='$ '

Hope this helps!
